# Cannot read all the rows of Excel with Spring MVC using Apache POI

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I have created this code to read the contents of excel files using Apache POI. I am using Intellij Idea as editor but when i ran the code i have a problem: only read the first row and not the rest. What's the problem? The content of excel is the following:

My dependencies with Maven:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
package com.ferreteria.ferreteria;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class ExcelService {

    public static void leer() {
        String nombreArchivo = "Libro1.xlsx";
        String rutaArchivo = "C:\\Users\\54261\\Downloads\\" + nombreArchivo;

        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(rutaArchivo))) {
            // leer archivo excel
            Workbook worbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

            //obtener la hoja que se va leer
            Sheet sheet = worbook.getSheetAt(0);
            //obtener todas las filas de la hoja excel
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

            Row row;

            // se recorre cada fila hasta el final
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                //se obtiene las celdas por fila
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                Cell cell;

                //se recorre cada celda
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    // se obtiene la celda en específico y se la imprime
                    cell = cellIterator.next();
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" | ");

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

[Excel with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujvLB.png)

The result was:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlVNB.png)

I'm trying to read all the excel file

Comment: `cell.getStringCellValue()` only works if the cell contains a string, else it throws exception. So your program breaks on second row at the cell having numeric content 1. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents for how to get cell contents properly.

Comment: Try to for loop using sheet.getLastRow()